# vb.net exporting datagrid values to excel via array

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to export datagrid values to excel using an array..
I get an error "`ComException was unhandled`" in the following line:

```
 xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Resize(DataGridView1.Rows.Count, DataGridView1.Columns.Count).Value = myArray
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this MSDN page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302094) for more info. Try the following

```
    Dim myRange as Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", Reflection.Missing.Value)
    myRange.Resize(DataGridView1.Rows.Count, DataGridView1.Columns.Count)
    myRange.Value = myArray
```

This is assuming that your `myArray` is a two dimensional array.

Comment: thanks... i still got an error Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' to 'Excel.Range'.

Comment: @user2444712 Then change the `Excel.Range` in my answer to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` - you might me importing the `Microsoft.Office.Tools` namespace. Also make sure that your Excel application object and your worksheet, `xlWorksheet`, are also coming from the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace

Comment: still an error                                                          "Property access must assign to the property or use its value. " with the line "  myRange.Resize(DataGridView1.Rows.Count, DataGridView1.Columns.Count)"

Comment: i have importer micorsoft.office.interop.excel                                and i have declared as                                                                     Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workshe           Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value